# Invoke an url with parameters using curl from command line and in a PHP code

Tags: php, curl

I've to invoke this url in my Ubuntu 15.10 ...

```
http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101
```

using `curl` both from command line and from PHP.

I've notice that no parameters are considered if I simply submit

```
curl 'http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101'
```

You can note that no number appears in the result, exactly the same behaviour that you've if submit

```
curl 'http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/'
```

The same using this PHP code

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101';


    //#Set CURL parameters: pay attention to the PROXY config !!!!
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $greenWaitingNumber = $xpath->query('/html/body/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/section/p');


    foreach( $greenWaitingNumber as $node )
    {
      echo "Number first green line: " .$node->nodeValue;
      echo '<br>';
      echo '<br>';
    }


?>
```

How may I using the url parameter both using `curl` from command line and in my PHP code?

Comment: What about using postman to get the right command? you can import your PHP code and then export to command line

Comment: do you have any sample? I don't know postman ... :-(

Comment: Did you tried reinstalling curl on ubuntu `sudo apt-get install curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The site makes an AJAX request**

You didn't mess anything up. The html is empty at first, then it loads code.js, which makes a request to gtotal.php with the id. You can see all this if you open up the network tab in chrome dev tools.

**To get the data:**

```
curl http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/gtotal.php?id=01090101
```

The parameters are sent, but the javascript part never runs.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting from postman would result on something like this

```
curl -X GET 'http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101'
```

you also can check this tutorial https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

Comment: I've tried `curl -X GET \ 'http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101'` but  it doesn't work ... `curl: (1) Protocol " http" not supported or disabled in libcurl` .. trying `curl -X GET "http://listeps.cittadellasalute.to.it/?id=01090101"` I obtain the same behaviour as before ...

Comment: what's the response?

Comment: did you try this solution? https://askubuntu.com/questions/821186/protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl/821993

Comment: Ok, I've just updated main response, apparently we have to use -XPUT